# Android 5 multi-user on Tablets and permissions

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-permissions

Use case: User 0 accepts permissions and installs app "A" via the PlayStore. User 10 (new user), is also interested in app "A" and when he/she tries to install it, the pay Store presents the same permissions acceptance dialog.

I could reproduce the above use case on 4.4. As expected, the permissions screen was not suppressed for the new user. However, I heard rumors that on Android 5 (on tablets), for shared apps, the new user will NOT be presented with the permissions. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

Per http://www.androidcentral.com/lollipop-brings-proper-multi-user-accounts-your-phone

> Accepting new permissions for an app on one account accepts them
>   across all accounts

But, this is on a phone. Is this experience on a tablet too?